# Menu with images and... thing

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, alignment

So, I want to make a menu like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfew2.png

BUT!!!! I can't make it =(
Look at my code:

**CSS:**

```
 .abas {
background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.0);
height: 70px;
width: 1024px;
color: #616161;
font-size: 20px;
margin:0 auto;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Roboto Slab Light', serif;
}

 .csq {
    position: relative;
    top: 45%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
} 

 a { color: inherit; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="abas"><div class="csq">
<a href="loja.html">LOJA</a>
<img src="Barratopo_assets/Bolinha.png">
<a href="catalogo.html">CATÁLOGO</a>
<img src="Barratopo_assets/Bolinha.png">
<a href="revenda.html">REVENDA!</a>
<img src="Barratopo_assets/Bolinha.png">
<a href="contato.html">CONTATO</a>
<img src="Barratopo_assets/Bolinha.png">
<a href="sobre.html">SOBRE NÓS</a>
</div></div>
```

And then it looked like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fGzh.png

I guess that my code is a mess, but... I'm new in this html/css/thing world, so... can you help me? (I'm also new in this english world, sorry ;-;)

Oh, I want to make the "Loja" item as a dropdown menu, so... if you can help me with that too I'll would be extremely greatful c:

Dictionary:
Loja: Store ---
Catálogo: Catalogue ---
Revenda!: Resale! ---
Contato: Contact ---
Sobre nós: About us ---
Bolinha.png: that little red circles

Comment: Try using padding to create spacing between the links and the images

Comment: Can you give me a example? Like... I don't know how to do that e.e

Comment: See @Rachel Gallen's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this fiddle for the spacing between the links and images : https://jsfiddle.net/ghysnxj7/1/, just adding a class `img`with a property of `margin: 0 56px;` is enough.

About the dropdown, that can be achieved with Javascript, but since you are new to HTML/CSS I would highly recommend to first have the basic of those two down.

There are plenty of tutorials in https://www.codecademy.com/es!